Get Maximum Supported Hardware Version for VMware Virtual Machine using PowerCLI
I'm trying to retrieve maximum supported Hardware version for a VM using Powershell. I'm getting other max supported details but no max supported hardware version.
PowerCLI Version:12.6.0
$vm = Get-VM -Name TESTVM01
$esxiHost = $vm.VMHost
$hwver = (Get-VMHost -Name $esxiHost | Get-View)
$hwver.Config.Product

I want to get maximum supported Hardware version for a VM using Powershell.
